# Bluetooth buffer read/write speed impact on scanning beacons

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

Does Bluetooth buffer reading and writing speed has any impact on scanning beacons to find the nearest beacon.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what buffers you are referring to, either at the Bluetooth chip level, the native Bluedroid level, within the Bluetooth API level in the Android OS, or within the Android Beacon Library or application code.

In a more general sense, mobile device processing speed can affect the ability to detect beacons in extreme situatioins.  In cases where large numbers of Bluetooth beacons are in the vicinity (e.g. hundreds within a 40-50 meter range) an Android phone can become unable to parse all packets, especially for beacons teansmitting at 10 Hz or more.  When this happens, some packets get ignored.

The consequence of this is fewer statistical samples of RSSI to be used to do distance estimates, yielding a somewhat higher error noise on the distance estimate.